# Change URL in new Firebase (from May 2016)

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Earlier when using Firebase, there was an option to use our own url like **myapp.firebaseapp.com** (including *firebaseapp.com* part). But from May 2016, when I create a project, it gets an auto-generated URL like **my-app-1c75b.firebaseio.com**, and I cannot find place to edit that (because 1c75b part in URL is not nice). I want to know is there any way to edit that like before?

*Note - I don't want to use a paid domain like www.example.com. I just want to customize my Firebase URL as myapp.firebaseapp.com*

Answer (score 13):

When you create a project in the new Firebase console, it will indeed add a "random" code to the project name. There is currently no way to prevent this code in the new console.

When you upgrade an existing project from firebase.com into the new console, the app name will remain unchanged. So if you already have `myapp.firebaseapp.com` on a firebase.com project, you will keep that URL after importing/upgrading.

Answer (score 6):

When creating a new project, you get an screen where you can enter the name.
In the textfield for project-id ou can enter a project-id.

**your project-id needs to include a dash**

when it doesn't, it will say something like, it is already used or it places the dash itself, with some custom characters.

The project-id itself is fixed, so you should create a new project and copy everything.

Comment: This needs to go to the top. Be careful when creating a new project; if you specify a name that's either not unique or that doesn't contain a dash, the project ID will automatically be appended with "-xxxxxx". You cannot change the project ID at a later stage.

Comment: It doesn't have to have a dash. I have many which don't have dashes. You just need to make sure you're the first one to own that name, so that you don't need any dashes and other characters.

Answer (score 4):

When you create your project the url is based on the project name you give.  If your project name is "Foo Bar", your url will be https://foo-bar.firebaseapp.com (assuming it isn't already taken).

Comment: It is not like what you said.

Comment: I mean if you create a project named "Foobar", firebase will add a random number followed your name "foobar-xxxxxx".

Comment: My guess is that you weren't the first to try that project name, so it needed to add the number to make it unique. If you try something you are sure no one else would have yet I think it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Last week Create Project window was showing possible firebase.com subdomain that will be assigned while you were typing project name. It's first come - first served basis so if you type a name already taken it automatically adds some character-number combination at the end.

Today same window doesn't show that while typing, you can only see it after you create your project and go to settings dashboard, there is no way to change given subdomain on the same dashboard.

**Update 10.07.2017**

I'm getting random hex number added from time to time, I can't always get plain name even if name is supposedly original one.

Answer (score 3):

If you choose a name unique enough within Firebase, they will give you a domain for your app as in https://myapp.firebaseio.com. 
I tried several times, sometimes it gives something like https://project-(long-random-number-sequence).firebaseio.com and other times something like what you've encountered. My personal experience shows if you give your app a name suffixed with "app" then you have a higher chance of being unique and getting the "nice" URL.

Comment: This is useful information, but it doesn't answer the question: "is there any way to edit [my firebase app url]?"

Answer (score 2):

Scroll down in '**Manage Site**' and **create a new site**, then **deploy** there.

You can't change your domain, but you can change the host! You can make as many sites as you want.